# Clicking an element using casperjs's evaluate function and jQuery

Tags: jquery, casperjs, evaluate

I am trying to use jQuery and casperjs to click an element retrieved from the DOM.

```
casper.options.clientScripts = ["jquery-1.11.1.min.js"];
...
...
casper.then(function()
{   
    this.wait(2000,function()
    {
        this.evaluate(function()
        {

        var element = $('h4:contains("test")').prev().find('.delete');
        $(element).css("background-color", "red");

        $(element)[0].click();
        });
     });
)};
```

I have used

```
$(element).css("background-color", "red");
```

to see exactly what element jquery is selecting, (I have used capture() to see what is happening on the webpage) and it has selected the correct one.
I have tried my code on Firefox's firebug dev tool and it works fine, but I cannot get the click function to work at all.

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: Ok sure Ill look into them

Comment: So I looked into this and got 
    Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(element)[0].click()')

I'm not entirely sure why this is occurring though.

Comment: Are trying to click a button on a google site by any chance? If not, please post the abbreviated markup. If yes, this will probably never work. Do you see errors with my suggested methods. Please try all of them and write what happened with all of them.

Comment: The only error I get still is that $(element)[0].click(); is undefined. Its not a google site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple things.

1. Using the jquery [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

   ```
   element.click();
   ```
2. Using `onlick`

   ```
   element[0].onclick();
   ```
3. Using `onlick` call

   ```
   element[0].onclick.call(element[0]);
   ```
4. Do a part of this using XPath with `casper.click`

   ```
   var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
   this.evaluate(function(){
       var $element = $('h4:contains("test")').prev().find('.delete');
       $element.css("background-color", "red");
   });
   this.click(x("//h4[contains(.,'test')/preceeding-sibling::*[1]//*[contains(@class,'delete')]]"));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I Tried your suggestions but to no avail. The XPath you supplied could not find the element, but Ill look into that further. Im new to XPATH.