# CasperJS submitting with form fields that do not exist

Tags: casperjs

I have a form I need to submit that has dynamically added inputs. Using Casper to click on the element that creates the inputs appears to have no effect.

Is there a way to add these inputs to the dom with CasperJS? If not, is there another solution to submit a form with additional values beyond what's in the dom at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run plain javascript in the DOM context/page context through <kbd>[casper.evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)</kbd>. A part of that may look like this:

```js
casper.evaluate(function(formSelector, values){
    var form = querySelector(formSelector);
    for(var key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hidden = document.createElement("input");
            hidden.type = "hidden"
            hidden.name = key;
            hidden.value = values[key];
            form.appendChild(hidden);
        }
    }
}, "#form", {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"});
```

Keep in mind that `evaluate` is sandboxed and the exchange of objects is limited.

---

I still suggest that you try to fix the clicking issue. Mocking some call may be acceptable in the short run, but if you try to create a big test suite, you will need to maintain the codebase and this will be horrible to maintain.

Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

If this doesn't reveal anything, see my suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875543/1816580).